# Resource NotfoundException when create new activity

Tags: android, exception, layout, resources, r.java-file

I am building a new android project which import from my old project.After I made some modifications and create a new activity, I noticed that in logcat there are some **yellow** error report whenever I open a new activity when running the app.

I have tried many ways offered online, like clean the project, or move all the class into one package, or close all the layout in the editor, or delete the R file.
Kind of crazy, any help would be appreciated.

Errors are as followings:

```
01-17 14:18:20.112: W/ResourceType(6671): Requesting resource 0x7f090001 failed because it is complex
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671): Failure retrieving text 0x7f090001 in package study.runtracker
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f090001
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:994)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadLabel(ComponentInfo.java:85)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-17 14:18:20.122: W/PackageManager(6671):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are the reference of 0x7f090001 in R file:

```
 All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. 
         */
        public static final int AppTheme=0x7f090001;
    }
```

Thanks for your suggestions, but problem is still here, Following is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="study.runtracker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <permission  
        android:name="study.runtracker.permission.MAP_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="study.runtracker.permission.MAP_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="study.runtracker.RunListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="study.runtracker.RunActivity" 
                  android:label="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>
         <activity android:name="study.runtracker.RunMapActivity" 
                  android:label="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="study.runtracker.map.OSMActivity" 
                  android:label="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="study.runtracker.LocationReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name ="study.runtracker.ACTION_LOCATION"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="study.runtracker.DeadReckoningService"></service>
         <meta-data 
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="balabala"/>
    </application>
```

Comment: post the relevant code also

Comment: Relevant code would be e.g. the manifest

Comment: This: **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f090001** makes me think of a typo in strings.xml... or there's a cross reference in R.java that points to both a theme and a String? Try deleting R.java and let it re-create

Comment: try to restart Eclipse, sometimes it knows to go mad... and post your XML where you are referencing the AppTheme

Comment: I also checked the R file, there are no cross reference here, neither restarting Eclipse works nor rebuilding the R file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<activity android:name="study.runtracker.RunActivity" 
              android:label="@style/AppTheme" >
```

`label` cannot be a `style` resource. It should be a `string`, for example `@string/app_name`.

The same applies to some other activities in the manifest as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Iaalto, that is such a stupid mistake.